# Rails form associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I currently have a form in my application that uses select form helpers. It accesses 2 variables:

```
@user = ['JM', 'JH', 'RY']
@name = ['JASON', 'JOHN', 'RYAN']
```

My form looks like:

```
  <%= form_for(:event, :url => {:action => :update, :id => @event.id}) do |e| %>
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Initails</th>
          <td><%= e.select(:initials, (@user)) %></td>
          <th>Priroty</th>
          <td><%= e.select(:priroty, (1..10)) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <td><%= e.select(:name, (@name)) %></td>
          <th>Event</th>
          <td><%= e.text_field(:event_name) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Deadline:</th>
          <td><%= e.datetime_select(:deadline, :order => [ :month, :day]) %></td>
          <th>Complete ?</th>
          <td><%= e.check_box(:complete) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Event Description</th>
          <td><%= e.text_area(:event_description, :size => '80x10') %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Comments</th>
          <td><%= e.text_area(:comment, :size => '80x10') %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
      <table>
          <div class="actions">
            <%= e.submit %>
          </div>
      </table>
  <% end %>
```

When I select my initials and it shows @user, I am trying to populate the name field that uses @name. Does anybody know how to associate the 2 so when I select JM for instance it pulls up Jason in the name field?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it without `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [observe_field](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/observe_field)

And this [tutorial](http://www.plexusweb.com/staff/charlie/blog/post/302/Dynamic-Select-Menus-in-Rails-using-ObserveField)